# URL.openStream throws an error

Tags: java, spring, url

Please help me to resolve the issue, I am trying to write a code to generate PDF using the Apache FOP. I have developed XSL-FO, which is in resource folder of the application i.e src/main/resource. 
Now when I am testing through Junit it is working fine, but when I try from the application I am getting an issue.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abc\development\Eclipse\eclipse\file:\C:\Users\abc\development\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\dmu-portal-ui\WEB-INF\lib\XYZservices-1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!\XSLtemplate\templateSummary.xsl (The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
```

**Code**

```
public String createPDFFile(ByteArrayOutputStream xmlSource, String templateFile) throws IOException {
        File file = File.createTempFile("caseSummary-" + System.currentTimeMillis(), EXTENSION);
        URL url = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/" + templateFile).getPath()).toURI().toURL();
        //URL url = new File(templateFile).toURI().toURL();
        //URL url = new URL(templateFile);
        // creation of transform source
        //StreamSource transformSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + templateFile));
        StreamSource transformSource = new StreamSource(url.openStream());
        // create an instance of fop factory
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
        // a user agent is needed for transformation
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        // to store output
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfoutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlSource.toByteArray()));
        Transformer xslfoTransformer;
        try {
            TransformerFactory transfact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            xslfoTransformer = transfact.newTransformer(transformSource);
            // Construct fop with desired output format
            Fop fop;
            try {
                fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, pdfoutStream);
                // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO)
                // must be piped through to FOP
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
                // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                try {
                    // everything will happen here..
                    xslfoTransformer.transform(source, res);
                    // if you want to save PDF file use the following code
                    OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);
                    out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);
                    FileOutputStream str = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    str.write(pdfoutStream.toByteArray());
                    str.close();
                    out.close();
                } catch (TransformerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FOPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }
```

**Problem I see**
At url.openStream when trying with from Application, path is duplicated, but when accessed from Junit it is working good.

Technology Stack
JDK : 1.7
Spring : 4.1.5

Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: What is the value of `templateFile` when this occurs?

Comment: The point of placing resources in the src/main/resources folder is for these resources to end up in the classpath of the application, and being able to load them using the ClassLoader, and thus **NOT** using file IO. Just use this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/foo/project/MyResource.xml") to have an InputStream.

Comment: @VGR templateFile value is "XSLTemplate\summary.xsl

Comment: @JB Nizet , I tried your solution, I am still getting the problem but different one, StreamSource is throws a Malfunction. Ultimately, I need to send the XML data to generate the PDF using the XSL-FO. Please suggest or refer me to any good reference

Comment: If you want help about an exception, edit your question, post the updated code and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as JB Nizet stated, you should not use URL or File for reading your template.  You don't need either of those; you just need to read your packaged resource from an InputStream:

```
try (InputStream xslStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + templateFile)) {
    StreamSource transformSource = new StreamSource(xslStream);
```

Second, the Class.getResource and Class.getResourceAsStream methods (and their ClassLoader equivalents) require [a String argument containing forward slashes (`/`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-), on all platforms, even Windows.

So either change the calling code so it passes `"XSLTemplate/summary.xsl"`, or put something like this at the beginning of your method:

```
templateFile = templateFile.replace('\\', '/');
```